# \t Tab is lost in bash script

Tags: bash, sed, echo, cut

I'm reading a text file line by line in a bash script. The text file I'm reading is a tab separated csv - however when I try to cut the read line, it does not work, it seems like the \t is converted to a blank space somewhere

**Below code is not what I am doing finally - I have not yet implemented the actual workload to the code, until the data can be read reliably.**

```
for (( currlineno=2 ; $currlineno <= $maxlines ; currlineno++ )); do
currline=$(sed -n "$currlineno"p "$IMPORT_TABLE".csv )
echo $currline |cut -f2
done
```

now when I change the two lines like below it works

```
for (( currlineno=2 ; $currlineno <= $maxlines ; currlineno++ )); do
currline=$(sed -n "$currlineno"p "$IMPORT_TABLE".csv |tr '\t' ';')
echo $currline |cut -f2 -d ';'
done
```

but I cannot do it like that as my text file also contains ';' ',' and '.' in the fields. Tab is the only acceptable option for me, as my fields will never contain it.

Comment: Quote it: `echo "$currline" | cut -f2`

Comment: Or better skip `currline` and use: `sed -n "$currlineno"p "$IMPORT_TABLE".csv | cut -f2`

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I will have to extract each field with a cut, and I want to prevent reading the file for each 30 fields. So quoting the variable did the job for me. THANKS

Comment: The issue is with quoting but if you want to execute one or more commands per line of a file, the best way to do that is to use a `while read` loop, not to call `sed` once per line.

Comment: @SebastianHeyn: I recommend using awk here as that will avoid shell loop and both `sed` and `cut` commands.

Comment: @TomFenech yes, you are right. I usually do it like you proposed. However I need the line number in the final workload, as well as variable starting line offsets. I guess I could use a counter as well. but the for loop seemed the best q&d option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't double quote your variable.

```
tabbed=$'a\tb'
echo $tabbed : "$tabbed"
```

When bash sees the variable outside of quotes, it applies word splitting on its contents, and `echo` just outputs its parameters separated by spaces. Double quotes make the value one parameter, even if it contains whitespace, newlines, etc.